# How to add a customer address attribute to checkout onepage shipping address part?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have added a customer address attribute(select type) using Hwg attribute manager extension. It is working fine in the back end and front end. I want to add that attribute to checkout onepage shiping address part. Can some one give me a help with this.

[Hwg attribute manager extension](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?qltm5vd8n28m7bz)

Comment: you need to change the template: `app/design/frontend/[your package]/[your theme]/template/(checkout|customer)`

Comment: Thank you  FlorinelChis.